# How to change the value of js local variable when debug in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, debugging

When I debug javascript with the Chrome console, I want to change a local variable of a function. I know how to change the value of global variables, but how do I change the value of a local variable when debugging in the Chrome console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't *debug* in the Chrome console. You *do* debug in the Chrome debugger. And if you are stopped at a breakpoint in the debugger, you can use the console to change the value of any in-scope variable by assigning to it.

For instance, open dev tools and run this code, reading the comments:

```js
function foo() {
  var bar = 42;
  // Normally, you don't have to use a hardcoded breakpoint like
  // the one that follows, you can set a breakpoint from within the
  // debugger just by navigating to the line of code and clicking in
  // the left-hand gutter. But in Stack Snippets the easiest way to
  // do one is to use the debugger statement:
  debugger;
  // Now, when stopped on the breakpoint, type this in the console:
  // bar = 67;
  // ...and press Enter.
  // Then hit the arrow button to allow the script to continue
  console.log(bar); // ...and this will log 67 instead of 42.
}
foo();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try setting a break point where you would want to redefine the local variable's value to a different one. Then you get access to all the data in that scope.

This might help

[image]

Comment: What I want was logging 13 at the second time.

Comment: What does second time mean you can write as many console.log statements as you want when you are in that scope, it will still print 13, If you are saying when you are running the code again the second time then you have to make sure you set the variable again to 13 if you want to log it as 13